# navigation component and view model communication

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I'm currently using the new navigation component and sticking to the one activity principle, I'm communicating between my fragments using viewmodels, I currently have a scenario where to tie the view model to the fragment (don't want it tied to the activity, this data must die with this fragments lifecycle) I'm having to call

```
getParentFragment().getParentFragment().getParentFragment()
```

to me this seems wrong but I have tested it and it seems to work fine, for instance logging the hash codes gives me

```
D/EnvTabFrag: this fragment 62204288
D/EnvTabFrag: parent fragment 264756153

D/EnvTempFrag: this fragment 169781400
D/EnvTempFrag: parent fragment 66865393
D/EnvTempFrag: parents parent fragment 62204288
D/EnvTempFrag: parents parents parent fragment 264756153
```

can anyone tell me if theres something terrible that I'm doing here that maybe i don't see or understand, the only potential issue I can see are null pointers, is this an ok approach or is there something I'm missing? many thanks

an example snippet

```
locationPickerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getParentFragment().getParentFragment().getParentFragment())
      .get(LocationPickerViewModel.class);
```

Comment: `getParentFragment().getParentFragment().getParentFragment()`
 what is the scenario you want to go upto parentFragment??

NullPointer is the only enemy to your code now but take them seriously as you will never know why any of the fragment is null don't do it until you have any other choice .

Comment: thanks ill keep that in mind, and no I'm not moving to a parent fragment I'm associating a shared view model with a lifecycle

Comment: share the code where you are calling the getParentFragment for better understanding.

Comment: ok @Anmol edited the question to add a snippet